# Create Dictionary With Position of Character and its Respective Count

Tags: python, python-3.x, etl

I have multiple strings like:

```
0000NNN
000ANNN
```

I wish to get a dictionary which has the position of the character in each string as the key and the count of its respective 0 as the value (If the character is NOT 0, it can be ignored). So for the above strings, the output would be:

```
1:2
2:2
3:2
4:1
5:0
6:0
7:0
```

So far i tried this:

```
ctr=1
my_dict={}
for word in string_list:
    for letter in word:
        if letter == "0":
            if ctr not in my_dict.keys():
                my_dict[ctr]=1
            else:
                my_dict[ctr]+=1
        else:
            pass        
print(my_dict)
```

What am I doing wrong as the output is not correct?

Comment: Are the strings guaranteed to be of the same length?

Comment: @Durtal Yes, same length always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you never increases and resetting `ctr` and not adding `my_dict[ctr]=0` for 5,6,7. Something like this should work:

```
string_list = ['0000NNN','000ANNN']

my_dict={}
for word in string_list:
    ctr=1 #Moved
    for letter in word:
        if letter == "0":
            if ctr not in my_dict.keys():
                my_dict[ctr]=1
            else:
                my_dict[ctr]+=1
        else:
            my_dict[ctr]=0 #Added
        ctr+=1 #Added
print(my_dict)  #{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along the following lines should point you in the right direction:

```
strings = ["0000NNN", "000ANNN"]

d = {i+1: sum(s[6-i] != "0" for s in strings) for i in range(7)}
# {1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0}
```

The `6` six would be `length-1` in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) in the following way:

```py
>>> Counter(i for string in strings for i, c in enumerate(string, start=1) if c == '0')
Counter({1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not incrementing ctr, so ctr == 1 always. But, that alone won't get you what you want. Right now, you're counting all of the '0's in all of your words and storing them in the dictionary key '1'.

Instead, you want to keep track of the position and the count separately.

```
my_dict = {}
for pos in range(7):  # assuming your "words" are the same length - 7 chars
  my_dict[pos] = 0
  for word in string_list:
    if word[pos] == '0':
      my_dict[pos] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `zip()` like this.

```
s = ["0000NNN", "000ANNN"]
d = {}
for i,v in enumerate(zip(s[0], s[1]),1):
    d[i] = v.count('0')

print(d)
```

```
{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0}
```